# sorting of elements in an array to return the index of the first occurence of a specific integer

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Given an array whose elements are sorted, return the index of a the first occurrence of a specific integer. we have to do this in sub-linear time. I.e. do not just go through each element searching for that element.
can we solve this using binary search???

Comment: Yes, you can solve it with a binary search, but you have to be a little careful to structure it to find the first occurrence rather than just any occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could perform a binary search on the array,it means the index the binary search resulted was not the first occurence.